# What is the name of this tree in our backyard?

Tags: identification, trees

These trees are in my backyard in New Jersey.

Can you tell me the name of the tree that is highlighted?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Gardening SE! Please post only one identification per question. Like all SE sites, we’re building a knowledge base that is supposed to be useful for more than one user, so we shouldn’t mix things up too much. That said, even as someone who’s been around the network, you may want to check out our [help] to learn more about this specific site and the tag wiki for [tag:identification] should also contain a few [useful pointers](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/tags/identification/info). Holler, if you need help!

Answer (score 2):

I highly suspect it is an Arborvaitae.

Comment: Den Warren, welcome! Please don’t forget to take the [tour] and browse our [help], especially [answer]. Also, is your answer a guess (as implied by the phrasing and the question mark) or truly an answer? The former is not what the askers here are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The tree outlined in red looks like some species of Thuja.

The truly knowledgeable people reading your question will probably be able to tell you the exact species and variety,  but it will help them if you can follow up with a location of where these trees are growing. You should be able to edit your original question with additional info.